# I have problem with slug and id in web route

Tags: laravel

i have this code

```
Route::get('posts/{id}/postedit','PostController@postedit');
Route::post('posts/{id}/postupdate','PostController@postupdate');
Route::get('posts/{id}/postdelete','PostController@postdelete');

Route::get('/{slug}', [
    'uses' => 'SiteController@singlepost',
    'as' => 'site.single.post'
    ]);

Route::get('/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'PendaftaranAlumniController@test',
    'as' => 'test',
]);
```

so here is the problem, when i run like this it `Route::get('/{slug}'` it works fine but `Route::get('/{id}'` it doesnt work
otherwise when i put `Route::get('/{id}` in the top it works fine, but `Route::get('/{slug}'` doesn`t work anymore.
how can i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Because both `/{slug}` and `/{id}` is getting treated as same by Laravel, both the routes `/{slug}` and `/{id}` will point any route defined earlier.

You can use it as it is, you need to tell Laravel that these two routes are different in any manner so that Laravel will treat it differently.

```
  Route::get('singlepost/{slug}', [
'uses' => 'SiteController@singlepost',
'as' => 'site.single.post'
]);

Route::get('test/{id}', [
'uses' => 'PendaftaranAlumniController@test',
'as' => 'test',
]);
```

Comment: i am so thankfull for your help my friend

Comment: Welcome, please approve/accept if this answer helped you.